# How can I make verbose output for specific task or module in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using AWS ec2 module and I would like to log what userdata is sent to AWS with every command, but I don't want verbose output from all other useless tasks.

Is there any way I can enable verbosity of the `ec2` module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with @techraf that there is no out of the box way to do this.
But Ansible is easily tuneable with plugins!

Drop this code as `<playbook_dir>/callback_plugins/verbose_tasks.py`:

```
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
import json

try:
    from __main__ import display
except ImportError:
    display = None

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    def v2_runner_on_any(self, result, ignore_errors=False):
        if (result._task.action in ['file','stat']):
            print '####### DEBUG ########'
            print json.dumps(result._result,indent=4)
            print '####### DEBUG ########'

    v2_runner_on_ok = v2_runner_on_any
    v2_runner_on_failed = v2_runner_on_any
```

You can tune what modules' results you want to print by changing `['file','stat']` list.
If you need only `ec2`, replace it with `['ec2']`.

Comment: Thanks for that. how to mention if i want to display what verbosity level like -v or vv or -vvv

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want to display this only on certain verbosity level, you can add `and display.verbosity >= 1` into `if` statement. If you want less data to be displayed, choose only required fields from `result._result`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a straightforward way.

As a workaround you could run the whole play with `no_log: true` and add `no_log: false` explicitly to your task calling `ec2` action. Then run the playbook with `-v`.

Comment: that also suppress normal output as well with output suppress message . not good at all

Comment: I cannot see anything about your expectations regarding other tasks in the question. You asked, so I answered.